# ActionScript 3 after seven buttons clicked go to next scene

Tags: function, actionscript-3, button

I have seven buttons (btn_one, btn_two, btn_three, ...) and when all of them were clicked (not in a row, just random) I want go to the first frame in the next scene. What does my code should look like?

Thank you!

Comment: What do you have this far?

Comment: Not much just the eventlistener for each button and the first function for btn_one (gotoAndPlay(1, "Scene2"). I don't know exactly how I have to start. Until now I made simple functions. ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const buttons:Array = [btn_one, btn_two, btn_three, btn_four, btn_five,  btn_six, btn_seven];

// dictionary to keep clicks state
const clicked:Dictionary = new Dictionary();

function buttonClickHandler(event:Event):void {
    // record specific button's click to a dictionary
    clicked[event.currentTarget] = true;

    // true, if all the dict keys have true values
    const allButtonsClicked:Boolean = buttons.every(
        function(button:Object, ...rest):Boolean {
            return clicked[button];
        });

    if (allButtonsClicked) {
        // remove all listeners
        for each (var button:DisplayObject in buttons) {
            button.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, buttonClickHandler);
        }

        //do whatever action you need. For example:
        gotoAndStop(/*neededFrame*/);
    }
}

// initialize dictionary values, and add listeners
for each (var button:DisplayObject in buttons) {
    clicked[button] = false;
    button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, buttonClickHandler);
}
```

haven't tested, it but should work. Anyway, the scheme should be valid.

Comment: Thank you very much, leetwinski.

Comment: If the buttons are MovieClips (dynamic), you could just set a dynamic property on them (clicked) and forgo the dictionary.

Comment: If I knew what to do, I would not have to ask.

Answer (score 0):

```
stop();

const buttons:Array = [btn_one, btn_two, btn_three, btn_four, btn_five,  btn_six, btn_seven];

// dictionary to keep clicks state
const clicked:Dictionary = new Dictionary();

function buttonClickHandler(event:Event):void {
    // record specific button's click to a dictionary
    clicked[event.currentTarget] = true;

    // true, if all the dict keys have true values
    const allButtonsClicked:Boolean = buttons.every(
        function(button:Object, ...rest):Boolean {
            return clicked[button];
        });

    if (allButtonsClicked) {
        // remove all listeners
        for each (var button:DisplayObject in buttons) {
            button.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, buttonClickHandler);
        }

        //do whatever action you need. For example:
        gotoAndStop(2);
    }
}

// initialize dictionary values, and add listeners
for (var button:DisplayObject in buttons) {
    clicked[button] = false;
    btn_one.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, buttonClickHandler);
    btn_two.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, buttonClickHandler);
    btn_three.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, buttonClickHandler);
    btn_four.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, buttonClickHandler);
    btn_five.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, buttonClickHandler);
    btn_six.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, buttonClickHandler);
    btn_seven.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, buttonClickHandler);
}
```

I tested the code of leetwinski and added the eventlisteners for my buttons, but it doesn't work. I get the error "1067: Implicit coercion of a value of type Class to an unrelated type flash.display:DisplayObject" What did I do wrong?

Comment: how did you created these buttons? it seems that these btn_one,... are class names. You should use instance names in code. Instance names should be set for every button on the stage.

Comment: I'm sorry. I forget to tell you that I used MovieClips instead of Buttons, because so I can change the color, or the shape when these "buttons" were clicked --> start in frame1; on click show frame2. I'm so sorry.

Comment: Is it anyway possible to use your code and expand the buttonClickHandler around with "when clicked --> show frame 2" for example button_one "MovieClip(btn_one).gotoAndPlay(2)"?

Comment: What do I have to enter at "...rest" in this area? [...] const allButtonsClicked:Boolean = buttons.every(function(button:Object, ...rest):Boolean [...] By the way, thank you for your patience.

Comment: don't have to care about this `...rest` thing. it is on of the function signature variants in as3. http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f56.html

Comment: made a minimum working example: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7Cb0lCQBhenbGtGcnVPZFdnbmc/view?usp=sharing . Notice that every button on stage has an instance name in properties tab, all of them are movie clips. Look at the code at the first frame. Feel free to ask any questions in chat, i'd try to answer them, if i have any spare time.

Comment: Your code works great, leetwinski. I have just one more question, but I can't chat with you, because I haven't enough reputation score, so I use the comment function again. What do I have to do if I want that each button show its second frame after clicking on it? I tried to write this "action" in the clickHandler-function, but it didn't work: instead of one clicked button shows the second frame ALL buttons show their second frame at the same time. Anyway thank you so much for your help.

Comment: how do you do it? you should add something like `event.currentTarget.gotoAndStop(2)` straight after `clicked[event.currentTarget] = true;`

Comment: I've been thinking too complicated and wanted to create own events for each button. For sure this can't work. Now the code works perfectly and you are just the best. Thanks again.